# unmatched while install flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

hello I hope you are doing well
Im facing this problem when I trying to install flutter what I have to do ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6GD5.png)

I have been follow a vid on YouTube and im attention to it but idk why this happen with me

Comment: Post text in a code block, not an image. Try moving that `"` that's on a line by itself to the end of the previous line.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to format code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)